What happens to private cloud chats on telegram after they're deleted by users?
Suppose if the chat history is deleted using delete for both parties option, is it immediately removed from the telegram servers? Or does telegram keep history of the chat stored on their servers even after it's deleted

Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by a "private chat". Do you mean a Telegram "secret chat" or are you using "private"  simply to indicate the chat was between only two users?

Telegram claims that when using “Delete for both parties”:

Messages are immediately removed from servers
Deletion happens server-side, not just on devices
No backups or logs are kept

However, Telegram's exact data retention policies aren't fully transparent, and there may be a brief delay in complete server removal.
